# lightdm restarts in cycle when using /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Tags: nvidia, xorg, lightdm, acer

I have a monitor Acer H233H and want to set resolution of 1920x1080. I googled it and found that it's necessary to use `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. I created this file using `sudo Xorg -configure`, copied it to `/etc/X11/` and restarted lightdm, but then lightdm restarts in cycle.

My `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier     "X.org Configured"
Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
Identifier  "Keyboard0"
Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
Identifier  "Mouse0"
Driver      "mouse"
Option      "Protocol" "auto"
Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier   "Monitor0"
VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier  "Card0"
Driver      "nvidia"
BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen0"
Device     "Card0"
Monitor    "Monitor0"
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     1
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     4
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     8
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     15
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     16
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     24
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

UPD: I tried https://askubuntu.com/a/617318/404225. My `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf` is now:

```
Section "Monitor"
Identifier "Monitor0"
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
EndSection
Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen0"
Device "Monitor0"
Monitor "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth 24
SubSection "Display"
Depth 24
Modes "1920x1080_60.00"
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using xorg.conf to set the resolution and not Settings -> Display?

To get it working again press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open a tty, then login.
Remove the xorg.conf file you created and reboot.

If the resolution you want is missing use:

- `cvt 1920 1080 60` to create a new modeline.
- `xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync`  to create a new Mode.

And then create the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf`.
With the following content:

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor0"
  <INSERT MODELINE HERE>
EndSection
Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Screen0"
  Device "<INSERT DEVICE HERE>"
  Monitor "Monitor0"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "<INSERT MODENAME HERE>"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: My Settings -> Display does not contain `1920x1080`.  It contains `1360x768`, but when I apply it, desktop is displayed with a significant shift. `Auto` on monitor doesn't help

Comment: There is no file attached, also please dont post such things in comments, edit your questen instead.

Comment: I've updated  my post

Comment: Your device name should not be the monitor. You can find the devicename with sudo `xrandr -q`

Comment: specified `VGA-0`, restarted lightdm, no effect.